# How to write a container class and import an instantiated object?

Tags: python, module

I would like to build a class to store an ensemble of data. That data are read from a structured file such as yaml, json or xml ... and they are not supposed to change. I wrote two classes. The first one describes one element of the data and the other the whole data. Actually, the class `AllData` is a kind of list or dict with a `__getitem__` method to obtain one `OneData` object.

```
class OneData(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

class AllData(object):
    def __init__(self, database):
        with open(database, "r") as f:
            data = read(f) # with read a yaml, json or other load function
        self._data = [OneData(d) for d in data]
        self._names = [data.name for data in self._data]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """ x.__getitem__(y) --> x[y] with y either group number or group name """
        if isinstance(key, int):
            item = self._data[key - 1]
        elif isinstance(key, str):
            try:
                item = self._pg[self._names.index(key)]
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError("%s is not a valid group name." % key)
        return item
```

I would like to know how to be able to use the `AllData` class, without the need of instantiated it ? (I wonder also if this is the best way to do this) I would like to be able to use the data from a simple import. There is no need of instantiate this class as it stores data that the end user must not modify. Thus all is contained inside the class from the beginning. For example :

```
from mymodule import AllData

# use data
AllData[1]
```

Comment: Why is `AllData` a class at all, instead of a list or an instance of a class?

Comment: Why not just put everything under the `OneData` class?

Comment: Will your `AllData` class have any other methods? If not, get rid of it and just initialize a module-level variable with all the data in it.

Comment: In `OneData` there is several methods to use the data. I wrote the `AllData` class mainly to implement a __getitem__ method and access data from several ways (index, name ...)

Comment: What will the `__getitem__()` method do, exactly? You still may not need a `class`...

Comment: `__getitem__` allows to access the data from both a number or a string. As if `AllData` was both a dict and a tuple.

Comment: How are you going to associate keys with each individual piece of data? `self.data` right now is just a list; what would `AllData['foo']` mean?

Comment: "I would like to know how to be able to use the `AllData` class, without the need of instantiated it" Why do you need a class at all if you are never going to instantiate it? I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do...

Comment: It sounds like you need a `dict`. Or whatever the `yaml`/`json` deserializes into...

Comment: I have juste updated the `AllData` class in order to give an example of `__getitem__`. Reading your comments, maybe I should instantiate it in the module and thus import the object ?

Comment: @Ger yes, that makes sense. But this approach: `item = self._pg[self._names.index(key)]` is less than optimal. If you want to access by strings or numbers, *just use a `dict`*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes but with a dict the key is either the number or the string, no both of them right ? Or I missed something I do not know.

Comment: You could have *two `dict`s*, or a `list` *and* a `dict`. But iterating over a list to find the index of your name is going to give you linear performance, when you could have contant time performance.

Comment: You can store the data in the dictionary using numeric keys, and then convert any keys you get which are string instances into a numeric value as necessary—or vice versa depending on which format is going to be the most common.